# Knockout Dialog with nested view model and templates

Tags: knockout.js

Hi Please check this fiddle.
When clicking on AddProduct a dialog should be shown.
I am using templates for all purpose.

http://jsfiddle.net/vivekcek/SqANG/

```
<table>
    <tbody data-bind="template: { name: 'catTmpl',foreach: Categories }">
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="button" value="Add Category" data-bind="click:$root.addCategory" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
<div id="details" data-bind="jqDialog: { autoOpen: false, resizable: false, modal: true, width:'auto' },openDialog: Open">
    <table>
        <tbody data-bind="template: { name: 'pdtTmpl', data: Products, foreach: Products }">
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<script id="catTmpl" type="text/html">
<tr>
    <td>
        Category Name:<input type="text" data-bind="value: CategoryName"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="button" value="Add Product" data-bind="click:$root.show"/>
    </td>
</tr>
</script>
<script id="pdtTmpl" type="text/html">
<tr>
    <td>
        Product Name:<input type="text" data-bind="value: ProductName"/>
    </td>
</tr>
</script>
```

And my script is given below. Please check the jsfidle.

Answer (score 0):

There were several mistakes in the code.
Now you can open the dialog.

You wrote :

```
new {pdt:''} /* instead of */  {pdt:''}
```

You forgot to specify the $root context before Products

I hope it helps.

[**See fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/SqANG/6/)

Comment: Thnx can you help me to complete, it in the pop up i want to add multiple products to the category.